# Combine this JS to use a single selector?

Tags: jquery

With the following Im getting the first 3 div.selector and removing the hidden class, and im also applying a function to the image thats within them.

```
    $(".selector").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden');

    $(".selector").slice(0, 3).find('img').each(imgFunction);
```

How can I rewrite this to be a single selector? My code works but it seems a bit clumsy.

Comment: Try this `$(".selector").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').find('img').each(imgFunction);`

Comment: Try with `$(".selector").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').find('img').each(imgFunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(".selector").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').find('img').each(showImg);
```

You can simply 'chain' removeClass and the other functions.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

[`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) returns the jQuery object, so you can chain your calls this way:

```
$(".selector")
  .slice(0, 3)
  .removeClass("hidden")
  .find("img")
  .each(imgFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can try this cleaner statement:

```
$(".selector:lt(4)").removeClass('hidden').find('img').each(imgFunction);
```